# Max number of shares on windows server 2008r2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

Is there a maximum number of shares that can be active at one time on windows server 2008r2?  I'm struggling with a weird issue with shares disappearing on a file server with about 2000 shares on it and can't figure out why they are working one day and not the next.

Additional info, How they are dissappearing is they were setup long time ago as each user being it's own share.  So a users home drive would be \server\usershare$.  Often we are seeing that a user is no longer able to map their home drive, and looking at the server we find that their home drive is no longer shared.

Yes, the server is domain joined.

Comment: Describe to us how they're disappearing.

Comment: And maybe a bit more about your environment - is the server in a Domain; how many shares are there;

Comment: 2k shares?!? I can't speak to whether or not that's causing a problem, but it seems like you're doing things wrong if you need that many shares.

Comment: I've added additional information as to how they are disappearing.  As far as the number of shares, when it was setup they decided that every user should have their own share instead of sharing the root of the folder and doing access based enumeration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shenan Stanley has expressed this well in words on similar Microsoft Community [Question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-file-shares-and/dd35f23b-180c-4ad6-a6a8-472a1de6491f):

> Like prior editions of Windows Server - **no max**.  Although after a
>   certain point the administrator may want to rethink their model if
>   they have so many shares they need to ask such a question.  ;-)

Now, you seem to have a model where every user has a home share `\\SERVER\username$`. I assume these are used in the AD attribute `homeDirectory` and they are stored in the same directory on the filesystem, say `D:\Home\username` connected as `H:`. I'd suggest sharing the `D:\Home\` instead of per-user shares, so that you'll have `\\SERVER\Home$\username` as a `homeDirectory` instead.

- Be careful with the [permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754178%28v=ws.11%29.aspx). (Probably this is why the per-user shares were used in the first place: someone didn't know how to correctly limit this with NTFS permissions, or it could be an old habit from the not-so-good old FAT32 times, when there was only share permissions.)

  - `\\SERVER\Home$` Share: All *Authenticated Users* should have Full Control.
  - `Home` folder root: *Domain Users* should have *Read & execute* access to *This folder only*.
  - Everyone has *Full control* over the own `Home\username` *folder, subfolders and files*.
- You don't have to change the home folder for each user manually. It is possible to choose multiple items in *Active Directory Users and Computers* and then use  username as a variable in *Properties for Multiple Items*, *Profile*, *Home folder* : *Connect* `H:` to `\\SERVER\Home$\%USERNAME%`.
- This has a major advantage in manageability: you don't have to create home shares or even home folders anymore. When you create new users and change their home folders with the `%USERNAME%` variable, the home folders will be created with correct permissions automatically.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response.  It makes sense why it was setup this way, as the guy who did it was the Admin from 30 years ago who came in to help after an exodus of sysadmins.  I think the next problem to solve after this is to get everything on a singe share, as right now they are spread across multiple drives on the server.

Comment: I feel your pain. :/ On the other hand 2008 R2 is rather old (Mainstream Support for SP1 ended 2015 and Extended Support will end 2020). One option is to get budget for a new server and revisit every configuration while migrating data. If the data is all over the place, the underlying cause might be wrongly estimated system resources.